# Using Webpack with React-router bundle.js Not Found

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, react-router

I build a project with Webpack and react-rounter.
this is my code:

```js
ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <Router history={ browserHistory }>
            <Route path='/' component={ App } >
                <IndexRoute component={ Home } />
                <Route path="purchase" component={ Purchase } />
                <Route path="purchase/:id" component={ Purchase } />
            </Route>
        </Router>
    </Provider>,
    document.getElementById('example')
);
```

When i request `"http://127.0.0.1:3001/purchase"`, it's work! but the address `"http://127.0.0.1:3001/purchase/a"` has error. look the error message:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UJuJ4.png)

My WebpackDevServer config is:

```js
new WebpackDevServer (webpack(config), {
    publicPath: config.output.publicPath,
    hot: true,
    noInfo: false,
    historyApiFallback: true
}).listen(3001, '127.0.0.1', function (err, result) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
        console.log('Listening at localhost:3001');
    });
```

I don't know what the matter, Help me!

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You are using a relative path to describe path of the bundle.js in your index.html.

You should use absolute path for bundle.js in your index.html

Absolute path contains the root directory and all other subdirectories in which a file or folder is contained.

If it's in the same path with your index.html.

eg.

`public/index.html`

`public/bundle.js`

This would solve your problem.

```
<script src="/bundle.js"></script>
```

Comment: very awesome! I wish I found that answer few hours ago :p

Comment: But my index.html doesn't have bundle.js in the file, it's inserted automatically somehow and with a relative path.

Answer (score 17):

If you happen to be using the [`HtmlWebpackPlugin`](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/html-webpack-plugin/) editing directly `index.html` is **not** an option. So, to fix this particular issue, add `publicPath` and specify `/` as the root folder inside `webpack.config.js`:

```
const path = require('path')

module.exports = {
  entry: './app/index.js',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    publicPath: '/'
  },
  // more config stuff goes below..
}
```

**Don't forget to restart the webpack dev server for these changes to take effect**

More info about `publicPath` [here](https://webpack.js.org/guides/public-path/).

Comment: It works for my project. Thank you. ( react 18, webpack 5)

Answer (score 13):

Adding `<base href="/" />` to head tag of my index.html file before including any scripts worked for me.

Comment: You have no idea how long I tried to fix my webpack config (days) only to find out that these 17 characters weren't even related to webpack. Thank you.

Comment: @MichaelCox Aah, JS is funny sometimes. Cheers anyway!