# Facing difficulty with configuring dynamic url params using react-router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I am trying to create dynamic URLs to render different content based on `URL params`.

When I use:

```
<Route path="/example/:id" component={Example} />
```

and then if I go to */example/99* on my browser, I am getting an error message on the console that says:

> GET http://localhost:8080/example/bundle.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)

However, when I remove the forward slash before the param then it works fine. E.g. when I use:

```
<Route path="/example:id" component={Example} />
```

and then if I fo to */example99* on my browser, I am getting the expected results.

How do I solve this, given I want to use `/` while routing to different ids?

PFB the entire **Routes.js** file content. Everything works fine until I add `/` before `:id`

```
import React from "react";
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Switch, Link, NavLink } from "react-router-dom";
import ExpenseDashboardPage from "../components/ExpenseDashboardPage";
import AddExpensePage from "../components/AddExpensePage";
import EditExpensePage from "../components/EditExpensePage";
import HelpPage from "../components/HelpPage";
import NotFoundPage from "../components/NotFoundPage";
import Header from "../components/Header";

const AppRouter = () => (
    <BrowserRouter>
        <div>
            <Header />
            <Switch>
                <Route path="/" component={ExpenseDashboardPage} exact={true} />
                <Route path="/create" component={AddExpensePage} exact={true} />
                <Route path="/edit:id" component={EditExpensePage} />
                <Route path="/help" component={HelpPage} exact={true} />
                <Route component={NotFoundPage} />
            </Switch>
        </div>
    </BrowserRouter>
);

export default AppRouter;
```

Comment: Could you please provide a full example of your code or create a [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/)? (P.S. Try to add `exact` prop to `Route` component (e.g. `<Route exact ... />`))

Comment: I think it is just the problem of how you add your script in your html

Comment: Added the entire code example for the routes page. I tried setting exact to true, but did not work either. Do let me know if the example is enough. All the other routes work fine.

Comment: `<Route path="/edit:id" component={EditExpensePage} />` here you haven't added slash in path, between `edit ` and `:id`

Comment: @McRist: Yes, that is the only way I am able to get this to work. If I add the slash, the app breaks.

Comment: I've created [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/embed/condescending-jackson-lpm4g) with your example. It works correctly. Do you use `create-reacta-app` or you use custom webpack configuration? If custom try to enable `historyApiFallback` (e.g. `module.exports = {
  //...
  devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: true
  }
};`

Comment: Thanks for your response. Appreciate it. Yes, I am using custom webpack config and I had already set historyApiFallback: true.

Comment: What is your `public path`? in the webpack file?

Comment: You may be linking your script file wrong. Check out this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37970251/12092655.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why, but rolling back to react-router-dom@4.1.2 fixed this for me.

Answer (score -3):

I was getting the same problem while learning Andrew Mead React JS class.
By the way I fix this problem by using `":"` instead of `"/"`. I really don't know exactly what is the problem. But I fix this here is the code:

Before Problem:

```
<Route path="/edit/id" component={EditExpansepage} />
```

I solve this by using this line:

```
<Route path="/edit:id" component={EditExpansepage} />
```

and from browser I sending this URL:

```
http://localhost:8080/edit:99
```

Comment: You did not add the code you mentioned in your answer. The formatting is poor and you have not added enough information as to why your solution works. You need to do more research before you can post a proper answer. Also, when there's code involved, try to add relevant code snippet that can demonstrate your solution.