# Webpack Bundling with React Router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, react-router, webpack-dev-server

Everything was working dandy then for some reason I decided to update some packages. Bad move.

I'm using React.lazy and Webpack to code split and bundle my JavaScript. If I'm at the root URL (`http://localhost:9000/`) there's no problem. It will load `http://localhost:9000/dist/24.js`. But if (using react-router) I'm anywhere down in the app, say `http://localhost:9000/page/category/` it will try to load `http://localhost:9000/page/category/dist/26.js`. Obviously that's not where the files are saved.

I can ignore the problem in production by using a wildcard: `app.get('*/dist/:js' ...`, but I can't do that with my devServer. I'm sure there's a way to tell it to use the absolute path always, but I can't figure out how to do it. **How do I tell it to always load from `http://localhost:9000/dist/*.js`?**

Here's the relevant piece of `webpack.config.js`.

```js
    output: {
      filename: '[name].js',
      chunkFilename: '[name].js',
      path: path.resolve(process.cwd(), 'dist'),
      publicPath: 'dist/',
    },
```

I'm using webpack 4.41.2, webpack-dev-server 3.9.0, react-router 5.1.2, and react-hot-loader 4.12.16. If you're wondering why I'm using `process.cwd()` instead of `__dirname` it's because I'm using this file via symlinks in a handful of apps.

Answer (score 0):

Add `<base href="/" />` to `index.html` before any `<script/>`.

Found it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49920446/9211387).