# Dynamic routes not working for any routes besides '/'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, react-router

```js
import React from "react";
import { Home, Profile, Saved, Explore, Auth, Settings } from "./pages";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";

const App = () => {
    const routes = [
        { path: "/", component: Home },
        { path: "/profile/:id", component: Profile },
        { path: "/saved", component: Saved },
        { path: "/explore", component: Explore },
        { path: "/auth", component: Auth },
        { path: "/settings", component: Settings },
    ];
    return (
        <div className="bg-gray-200 w-full min-h-screen">
            <Router>
                <Switch>
                    {" "}
                    {routes.map((route, i) => {
                        return <Route key={i} exact path={route.path} component={route.component} />;
                    })}{" "}
                </Switch>
            </Router>
        </div>
    );
};
```

I can't seem to figure this out. If I make the first path dynamic it works. But the rest of the Routes don't work when I try and make them dynamic. Am I missing something, I checked around and looked at tutorials but couldn't find anything I would be missing

```json
{
    "name": "Twitter",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "description": "",
    "main": "index.js",
    "scripts": {
        "start": "webpack serve --mode development",
        "build": "webpack --mode production"
    },
    "keywords": [],
    "author": "",
    "license": "ISC",
    "dependencies": {
        "@babel/runtime": "^7.16.3",
        "@headlessui/react": "^1.4.3",
        "@redux-devtools/extension": "^3.2.2",
        "axios": "^0.24.0",
        "moment": "^2.29.1",
        "process": "^0.11.10",
        "querystring-es3": "^0.2.1",
        "react": "^17",
        "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
        "react-icons": "^4.2.0",
        "react-redux": "^7.2.6",
        "react-router-dom": "^5.3.0",
        "redux": "^4.0.5",
        "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
        "styled-components": "^5.3.0"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@babel/core": "^7.14.6",
        "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime": "^7.16.4",
        "@babel/preset-env": "^7.14.7",
        "@babel/preset-react": "^7.14.5",
        "autoprefixer": "^10.2.6",
        "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
        "babel-loader": "^8.2.3",
        "babel-polyfill": "^6.26.0",
        "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
        "babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.24.1",
        "css-loader": "^5.2.6",
        "file-loader": "^6.2.0",
        "html-webpack-plugin": "^5.3.2",
        "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^1.6.2",
        "postcss": "^8.3.5",
        "postcss-cli": "^8.3.1",
        "postcss-loader": "^6.1.0",
        "postcss-preset-env": "^7.3.2",
        "sass": "^1.35.1",
        "sass-loader": "^12.1.0",
        "style-loader": "^3.0.0",
        "tailwindcss": "^2.2.4",
        "webpack": "^5.41.1",
        "webpack-cli": "^4.7.2",
        "webpack-dev-server": "^4.7.4",
        "webpack-node-externals": "^3.0.0"
    }
}
```

edit: Here's my package.json file as well.

I was also getting this error in the console when trying out a dynamic path like '/profile/test' for example

GET localhost:8080/profile/index.bundle.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "dynamic" here in your question? What is the issue? I don't see any overt issue here in the code snippet you've shared. The code runs without issue here in a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/dynamic-routes-not-working-for-any-routes-besides-ross6).

Comment: What version of `react-router-dom`  are you using ?

Comment: Dynamic like if I wanted to access /profile/{userid} - this should load Profile component. But visiting for example '/profile/dsfs' doesn't load the Component. But if I added dynamic routing to the first path like '/:id' and went to 'sdfs' it would still load the Home Component just fine

Comment: @yousoumar "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0"

Comment: Is this code an accurate representation of the code you're actually running? Like I said, I see no issue with it and it runs correctly in a sandbox. Can you create a *running* codesandbox of your own that reproduces the issue that we could inspect and debug live?

Comment: @DrewReese The sandbox works how it should. Not sure why my code isn't working. It works if I don't add '/:id' to it so i'm assuming it a router issue

Comment: @DrewReese Yeah this is the exact code i'm running

Comment: Try reinstalling `react-router-dom` and restarting your development server. `npm un -s react-router-dom react-router; npm i -s react-router-dom@5; npm start`.

Comment: Do you happen to have any other routers in your app? Can you also share your package.json file?

Comment: @DrewReese updated with package.json and no the app.js is the only place I have routers

Comment: I think it may be a webpack issue; does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37962559/using-webpack-with-react-router-bundle-js-not-found/57715005 If not, can you share your webpack code?

Comment: @DrewReese Yes that solved the issue. Thank you so much!